# Is is possible to apply a spreadsheet number format to a cell that includes a cell value?

Tags: excel, number-formatting

I searched the internet and could not find an answer.

I am looking for a **NON-VBA** solution, and this is not using traditional conditional formatting that changes the colors or patterns.

Is is possible to apply a spreadsheet number format to a cell that includes a cell value?

For example:

```
Cell A1 = 100 
Cell B1 = 140 
Cell C1 = 180
```

I would like to enter the value 100 into cell A2 and have A2 formatted to display:

100 to 140

Then enter the value 140 into cell B2 and have B2 formatted to display:

141 to 179

Then enter the value 180 into cell C2 and have C2 formatted to display:

≥ 180

Thank you for your time

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: I figured that, but it was worth a try. Still hoping for a solution. Thanks

Comment: it is possible,  need to use custom formating

Answer (score 0):

you can do this, but it is a manual solution.  you need to choose custom format for each cell and adjust the formatting so it will be unique to each cell.  Its also going to be hard coded.

```
For first cell
Select cell A1
Select custom formatting
Enter the following format:  
    ###" to 140"
Enter 100 in cell A1

For second cell
Select cell A2
Select custom formatting
Enter the following format:
   "141 to 179"
Enter anything in cell A2

For third cell
Select A3
Select custom formatting
Enter the following format:
  "≥ "
Enter 180 in cell A3
```

Now I personally consider this a bad idea.  Its essentially hard coding all your formats.  To change the display you will need to edit each cells format.  However it will produce what you are looking for as a final result.

In the example below, column C is the values that were entered in column A.

[image: POC]

Comment: Thanks Forward Ed for your answer and the time you spent. It looks good, but I want the formats to be variables, and not to be hard coded. I guess that it is not possible.

Comment: The formats must be hard coded.  If you are making a table so that values range from 100 to 140 and you plan on using the numbers as break points for a look up or the like, you can make a table of 4 columns,  column 1 100, column 2 to, column 3 140, and column 4 your result.  then you just need to figure out with your fomulas if you want to use column 1 or column 3 for you look ups.